# Find the default library paths and default headers include paths

Tags: c, ubuntu, gcc, shared-libraries, header-files

I'm on an Ubuntu 22.04 system and I'm working with C language and libraries.

I know ( from different books, included "The Linux Programming Interface" by Kerrisk ) that this algorithm is used when looking for runtime shared libraries locations ( I just omitted the preloaded libraries for the sake of simplicity ) :

When RUNPATH field is specified (i.e. DT_RUNPATH is non-empty)

1 ) LD_LIBRARY_PATH

2 ) runpath (DT_RUNPATH field)

3 ) ld.so.cache

4 ) default library paths (/lib and /usr/lib)

In the absence of RUNPATH (i.e. DT_RUNPATH is empty string)

1 ) RPATH

2 ) LD_LIBRARY_PATH

3 ) ld.so.cache

4 ) default library paths (/lib and /usr/lib)

The problem is that most books say that generally speaking the default library paths are /lib and /usr/lib but they don't mention **HOW I CAN GET THE EXACT DEFAULT LIBRARY PATHS FOR MY SYSTEM**. What command can I use on my Ubuntu 22.04 system ?

**What about the default headers include paths ? What command can I use the get them ?

And finally what is the specific algorithm used in my ubuntu system when dealing with "headers.h" vs <headers.h> ?**

Comment: The search path for shared libraries has _nothing_ to with the search path for headers. You should ask one question at a time (it's free :-)